# Naming Convention for some conf files

Tags: linux, configuration

I am looking into many systems which pick a conf file from a location, lets say in this scenario I have a couple of configuration which hold information to send the logs to a different server. What i am confused at is the naming configuration of some conf files. The following are the files, What's with the naming convention going here:

```
/etc/rsyslog.d$ ls
20-ufw.conf  21-cloudinit.conf  50-default.conf  80-tomcat.conf  81-some-app.conf
```

Basically i am uunclear what/why the numbers?? What do they signify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They signify the order in which they are included and executed.

Read here why order matters: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/basic_structure.html#processing-order

Comment: so why not use 1 , 2 ,3 , 4 .. i mean wht does this randomness mean?

Comment: If you use 1- 2- and 3- and you later add a fourth include file, which you want to position between 2 and 3, there's no room. But if you use 10- 20- 30- you can put the new one at 25-